# When does a static variable is really initialized

Tags: java

I have a Java class:

```
Class A {
  static Object a = new Object();
  Object getObject() {
    return a;
  }
}
```

In above code. I want to ask when `object a` is really initialized. I have two answers for my question:

1. When Java program is started. a will automatically initialize, although we will never use it.
2. the very first time we call getObject(). So, I think this will be more optimize.

I don't know which really true behind the scene.

Comment: *I don't know which really true behind the scene.* Please do some research before asking a question.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the JVM loads class A, it executes "static" block of code and initializes static variables as well.